# PHP mail() on localhost with Comcast's SMTP Server not working

Tags: smtp, wampserver, php

I'm trying to use the mail() function on my computer so I can test the web application's system emails that I'm building for someone. In the `php.ini` file I changed `sendmail_sender` to my email address. The SMTP settings in `php.ini` are as follows:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.comcast.net
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

When I try sending mail with PHP, I get this error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.1.0
>   Authentication required in C:\wamp\www\register.php on line 28

Here is my PHP mail code:

```
$url = "http://localhost/activate.php?key=".$key;
$email_body = "Dear ".$name.",

Thank you for registering on Yamma.org! To activate your account, please click on the following URL: 

".$url."

If the above URL is not clickable, please copy the FULL URL and paste it into your browser's address bar.

Sincerely,
The Yamma Team
http://www.yamma.org";

mail($email, $settings['activate_email_subject'], $email_body, "From: ".$settings['emails_sent_from']);
```

Does anyone have any idea of why I could be getting this error? I don't think Comcast's SMTP server needs authentication, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it does or it wouldn't be saying that :).  To do authentication, you will need to use a library like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer, or Zend_Mail.

Comment: Oh, ok. So with one of those libraries would I still use Comcast's SMTP server?

Comment: You could.  It would likely be a violation of the Comcast ToS (not sure), but you definitely could.  Otherwise, you could either setup your own mail server (a bit of a pain to do the first time with not only the actual daemon, but also the MX records and whatnot) or use one whose ToS does allow things like this (once again: not sure if Comcast does or not).